# Add a number to a struct field

Tags: matlab

I am trying to figure a way to add a specific value to a struct field in MATLAB. For example:

```
a.w = a.w + 12;
```

But I get the following error message:

> Error using  + 
>   Too many input arguments.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the content of `a.w`? If it is a simple number, it works. Example: `a.w=1; a.w=a.w+12;` will return `13`.

Comment: I see you've been around SO lately, welcome! Please take a few minutes to read the [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on how to format your questions. This will help in the readability and findability of your questions and other users won't have to edit your question.

Comment: a.w has many values. For example a(1).w = 1, a(2).w = 5, a(3).w = 6.....

Comment: @Adriaan you are right. I'm sorry. I will